# Header tags for identifying layout structure elements?

Tags: html, accessibility

I am trying to apply better semantics and accessibility to my web pages.

I recently installed the Fangs add-on for Firefox to see what they look like in a screen reader. I am concerned with how all my sidebar and footer information appears crammed underneath my last content heading.

**Problem #1**

I would like to be able to break it up by using header tags (`<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc.) to designate "Sidebar" and "Footer" sections. *I am not sure if this is a proper usage of header tags.* While these sections are technically content, it feels a little odd to see them at the same hierarchy level as an article title.

**Problem #2**

*I also would like to keep these header tags for identifying layout structure elements invisible but still available to those that need it.* Using "visibility: hidden" leaves an undesired placeholder. Using "display: none" appears to produce the desired effect, but I have seen posts that suggest it may not work in actual screen readers. I am now tempted to use "position: absolute" and the negative "text-indent" trick to break the element out of the normal flow and push it off-screen.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen many sites using the `<h3>` tag being used in sidebars and footers. So, you can also follow the same. The `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags are generally used only once in a web page. `<h1>` for the title and `<h2>` for the tagline.

Well.. for the second problem, you can use a JavaScript to toggle the `display` property.

Answer (score 1):

These are my notes so far.

Some resources:

- [The global structure of an HTML document | W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5)
- [Using h1-h6 to identify headings | WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H42.html)
- [Using CSS to hide a portion of the link text | WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C7.html)
- [Invisible Content Just for Screen Reader Users | WebAIM](http://www.webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/)
- [On being heard but not seen | Access Matters](http://www.access-matters.com/2005/04/03/quiz-241-on-being-heard-but-not-seen/)
- [Screen Reader Visibility | CSS-Discuss](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=ScreenreaderVisibility)
- [Screen Reader Test Results | Access Matters](http://www.access-matters.com/screen-reader-test-results/)

Some examples in the wild:

**w3.org/WAI/** (h3.no-display)

```
position: absolute;
left: -999px;
width: 990px;
```

**diveintoaccessibility.org** (h2.invisibletitle)

```
display: none;
```

**standards-schmandards.com** (h1)

```
position: absolute;
left: -1000em;
margin-left: -1000em;
display: block;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

**yahoo.com** (h3.a11y)

```
position: absolute;
left: -5000px;
width: 100px;
```

**my.yahoo.com** (h3.a11y)

```
position: absolute;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

**gmail.com** (h2.u4w5cc)

```
position: absolute;
height: 9px;
left: 0;
top: -10000px;
```

**target.com** (h1.offscreen)

```
position: absolute;
left: -99em;
width: 90em;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `hr` element to separate the sections, for example:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<hr />
<div id="content"></div>
<hr />
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<hr />
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Additionally you could use the `title` attribute on the `hr` elements to describe the following section. But I don’t know how this is supported.